# Uniq static database context with iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis-7

I develop a web application ASP.NET MVC with EF5. I use static database context. But it raise an datareader error. Because static variables shared in application pool. I did not know. How can i change this settings with IIS. I need a quick solution. If i don't use my application crash at another part. 
Shortly i need uniqe db context with every request.

```
private static AppContext _db;
public static AppContext Create()
{
    //i need uniqe instance every request.
    return _db ?? (_db = new AppContext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i've solved it with ninject

```
_kernel.Bind<AppContext>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```